# Redirect React Router Route From onClick in Modal

Tags: reactjs, react-router, bootstrap-modal, react-router-dom, react-props

Below is code for the body of a sign up modal. How I would like it to work would be the user enters credentials and when they click submit they are automatically taken to the route "/secret" which is their dashboard.

Currently, when the user clicks submit an error is thrown and the alert "('Error logging in please try again')" appears. I only want this to happen if there is an error with their input (i.e. nonunique entry, not hitting requirements ect.)

This alert is thrown every time the user clicks submit regardless if the input hits requirements and is pushed to the database. Also for some reason react seems to over look the line of code to redirect the user to the desired route.

```
if (res.status === 200) 
{  this.props.history.push('/secret'); 
}
```

Is there a way to redirect the route if I receive a res.status === 200 while also keeping the condition to throw the error if it occurs?

signup.js (modal body)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import API from "../utils/API.js";
import { Container, Row, Col, Button, Alert, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';
export default class Signup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      username: ''
    };
  }
  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { value, name } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }
  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    API.signUpUser(this.state.email, this.state.username, this.state.password)
   
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          this.props.history.push('/secret');
        } else {
          const error = new Error(res.error);
          throw error;
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        alert('Error logging in please try again');
      });
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

        Email: <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="Enter email"
          value={this.state.email}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          required
        />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>

        Username: <input
          type="text"
          name="username"
          placeholder="Enter username"
          value={this.state.username}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          required
        />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>


        Password: <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Enter password"
          value={this.state.password}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          required
        />
         <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <Button type="submit" value="Submit" color="primary" className="btn btn-warning">Sign Up</Button>

      
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

app.js (react routes)

```
 <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <Route path="/hometwo" exact component={Home2} />
            <Route path="/secret" component={withAuth(Secret)} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
            <Route path="/signout" component={Signout} />
            <Route path="/loggedIn" component={withAuth(loggedIn)} />
          </Switch>
```

Signup User API

```
  signUpUser: function (email, username, password) {

    const signUpURL = "/api/user"
    // console.log("username " + username + "password " + password)
    return axios.post(signUpURL, { email,username, password }).then(result => result.data);
    // return axios.post(signUpURL, { email, username, password }).then(result => result.data);
    // .then(result => result.data);

  },
```

NEW Signup.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import API from "../utils/API.js";
import { Container, Row, Col, Button, Alert, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';
export default class Signup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      username: '',
 
    };
  }
  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { value, name } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }
  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // API.signUpUser(this.state.email, this.state.username, this.state.password)

      fetch('/api/authenticatesignup', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
      .then(res => {
        console.log("THIS IS res " + JSON.stringify(res.status));
        if (res.status === 200) {

          // alert("You can now go to your dashboard")
          // window.location.reload();

          // // alert("You can now go to your dashboard")
          this.props.history.push('/secret')
        } else {
          const error = new Error(res.error);
          // console.log("This is error on client side " + error)
          throw error;
          // alert('Error logging in please try again');

        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        alert('Error logging in please try again');
      });
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

        Email: <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="Enter email"
          value={this.state.email}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          required
        />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>

        Username: <input
          type="text"
          name="username"
          placeholder="Enter username"
          value={this.state.username}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          required
        />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>


        Password: <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Enter password"
          value={this.state.password}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          required
        />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <Button type="submit" value="Submit" color="primary" className="btn btn-warning">Sign Up</Button>


      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

API endpoint of signup in server

```
//authenticate checker signup
app.post('/api/authenticatesignup', function (req, res) {
  const { email, username, password } = req.body;
  User.create({
    email: req.body.email,
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  }, 
  
  function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500)
        .json({
          error: 'Internal error please try again'
        });
    }
    else {
      // Issue token
      const payload = { username };
      const token = jwt.sign(payload, secret, {
        expiresIn: '1h'
      });
      res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true })
        .sendStatus(200);
        console.log("New USER!" + req.body.email + req.body.password)
    }
  })


});
```

[image: res.status]

Comment: it seems that there is some issue with the api call, that's the reason the catch block is being called . check your console, what error is getting printed in console

Comment: can you console.log the response ?

Comment: if it show alert then it should print something to console, because you have this         console.error(err);
Can you show what the console says?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing the exact error and your api end points, and it also looks like you are sending your credential information without specifying the properties: usually you send an object, something like this:  `const userCredentials = { 
    email: this.state.email, 
    username: this.state.username, 
    password: this.state.password 
  }; 
  API.signUpUser(userCredentials)`

Comment: Updated the post with a screenshot of what's being received in the console and with the API code (below). I don't believe it's the API. The API is working  just fine whether I have the this.props.history.push("/secret") method or not. My issue is the redirect to the route ("/secret") isn't working. The API post occurring, but the redirect is not.

Comment: @SohailAshra made some updates above the error doesn't seem to be coming from the API

Comment: @DarthJS updates above

Comment: @AlexYepes updates above

Comment: What is the api response? It's seems that the response status code is not 200 .

Comment: console the response , I guess you don't receive status 200

Comment: @SohailAshraf the response from the server is 200 under. Screenshot above

Comment: @DarthJS update above

Comment: Could you log the response inside the then block

Comment: @SohailAshraf added line of code  ```  console.log("This is error on client side " + error) ``` I just got error in the console no details

Comment: @Dom Do you have this Repo somewhere? I think it would be a lot easier to look at the whole thing

Comment: I have added the sample code in the ans, try that and let me know what is logged in the console.

Comment: You receive a plain object with your login data, but you don't have status parametr, that's why if statement skiped

Comment: @Dom that's why asked you to include your api end point before, it is important to know how you configured your route in the backend to handle responses properly in the front-end

Comment: @AlexYepes ah understood, thanks folks. Setting up the status parameter in the backend now

Comment: @SohailAshraf made some updates I'm now getting the 200 response, but the route still isn't getting redirected. Instead the dashboard route (/secret) is being read as undefined, but it is in fact one of the routes defined in react router. New code for API start and end point is above as well as an image of the error

Comment: @DarthJS updates above

Comment: @AlexYepes updates above

Comment: you need to wrap the component with `withRouter`, I have updated the code please try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the component with `withRouter`.

> You can get access to the history object’s properties and the closest 's match via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import API from "../utils/API.js";
import { Container, Row, Col, Button, Alert, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';

class SignupComp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            username: '',

        };
    }
    handleInputChange = (event) => {
        const { value, name } = event.target;
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }
    onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // API.signUpUser(this.state.email, this.state.username, this.state.password)
        fetch('/api/authenticatesignup', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
                console.log("THIS IS res " + JSON.stringify(res.status));
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    // alert("You can now go to your dashboard")
                    // window.location.reload();
                    // // alert("You can now go to your dashboard")
                    this.props.history.push('/secret')
                } else {
                    const error = new Error(res.error);
                    // console.log("This is error on client side " + error)
                    throw error;
                    // alert('Error logging in please try again');
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
                alert('Error logging in please try again');
            });
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.state)
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                Email: <input
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="Enter email"
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    required
                />
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                Username: <input
                    type="text"
                    name="username"
                    placeholder="Enter username"
                    value={this.state.username}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    required
                />
                <br></br>
                <br></br>

                Password: <input
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    placeholder="Enter password"
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    required
                />
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <Button type="submit" value="Submit" color="primary" className="btn btn-warning">Sign Up</Button>

            </form>
        );
    }
}

const Signup = withRouter(SignupComp);
export default Signup;
```